# sort by two columns using sort and map in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, perl-data-structures

I have the list as

```
@emprecords = (
                  ['pavan',24,25000],
                  ['kumar',25,35000],
                  ['ajay',22,35000],
                  ['vijay',25,20000]
);
```

i need to sort them by lowest age first with highest slary first .

Comment: Should we guess which field is "age" and which is "slary"?

Comment: actually the second column is age and third column is salary..

Comment: Then perhaps you should write "salary" and not "slary".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<=>` for a numeric comparison and a conditional `or` to check the salary when age is equal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @emprecords = sort {
                $a->[1] <=> $b->[1]
                        or
                $b->[2] <=> $a->[2]
                }
                (  ['pavan',24,25000],
                  ['kumar',25,35000],
                  ['ajay',22,35000],
                  ['vijay',25,20000]
);

print Dumper \@emprecords;
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'ajay',
            22,
            35000
          ],
          [
            'pavan',
            24,
            25000
          ],
          [
            'kumar',
            25,
            35000
          ],
          [
            'vijay',
            25,
            20000
          ]
        ];
```

Comment: may i whats the use of 'or' in the sort ?

Comment: If the first comparison (age) is equal (meaning 0), then or kicks in and performs comparison by salary.